# How to concatenate string to razor model item in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
@integer.IntegerValue + " , ";
```

I hope it's obvious what I want to do. I'm sure it's painfully simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in parenthesis:

```
@(integer.IntegerValue + " , ")
```

Comment: Yes. That would do it.